# Python code to pass Multiple Key Value pairs in API request

Tags: python, api, for-loop, python-requests, key-value

```
import requests
import json

url = "abc.com/changes/add"

payload = json.dumps({
  "records": [
    {
      "key": "1.1.1",
      "value": []
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Csrf-Token': 'nocheck',
  'ExaAuthToken': 'asasasasasasasasasa',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': '*/*'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Hi,

Above Python request is for single key value pair. I'm looking for python code to send a python request using **for/while loop** for multiple pairs as shown below. value is always **[]**

```
payload = json.dumps({
  "records": [
    {
      "key": "1.1.1",
      "value": []
    },
    {
      "key": "2.1.1",
      "value": []
    }
  ]
})
```

Python code for to pass multiple key value pairs in python request.

Comment: How does the data look like from where to create these key, value pairs?

Comment: @YOLO 
keys are taken as input from other python code which downloads the feed periodically. There can be 'n' inputs. As I mentioned above value is always []. We should follow this structure as the API expect this format.